# Using a join and putting results of join in an array?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a users and a posts table:

Users

```
id | name
```

Posts

```
id | post | user_id (fk)
```

I want to get all users with their posts:

```
SELECT users.name, posts.post FROM users LEFT JOIN posts ON user.id posts.user_id
```

From the above query I get separate results for each post with repeated users information, e.g.

```
name | post
john | about me...
john | about my pets
....
```

I'm more looking for a structure where I have all of the posts grouped together, so in PHP I can loop through the array, something like:

```
[0]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(4) "john" ["posts"]=> array(22){....}
```

Comment: What's the question? Loop through the data and generate the array you want. Should be trivial.

Comment: Yeah, how would i do that? No way to do this in sql only?

Comment: While there are ways to do this, they are quite hideous hacks. Far more difficult than just doing it with php, and also likely to be far less reliable and far slower than doing it through php.

Comment: Just added an example of the hideous hack required to do what you want. I really do not recommend using it!

Answer (score 0):

Crude way to put it into an array in php:-

```
$sql = "SELECT users.name, posts.post 
        FROM users 
        LEFT JOIN posts 
        ON user.id posts.user_id 
        ORDER BY users.name, posts.post";

$db->query($sql) or die($db->error());

$out_array = array();

while($row_item = $db->fetch_assoc())
{
    $out_array[$row_item['name']][] = $row_item['post'];
}
```

Using GROUP_CONCAT you could do the below, but it is limited on the size of the output of posts for a user, doesn't really fix anything (and would have issues if any post contained the delimiting string, in this case #~# ).

```
$sql = "SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;

$db->query($sql) or die($db->error());

$sql = "SELECT users.name, GROUP_CONCAT(posts.post SEPARATOR '#~#') AS out_post
        FROM users 
        LEFT JOIN posts 
        ON user.id posts.user_id 
        GROUP BY users.name
        ORDER BY users.name";

$db->query($sql) or die($db->error());

$out_array = array();

while($row_item = $db->fetch_assoc())
{
    $out_array[$row_item['name']] = explode('#~#', $row_item['out_post']);
}
```

If you really wanted to you could use a variation of the above to manually build up the array of posts as a php serialised array. I have done this before, but only under exceptional circumstances (and having an array of strings makes it far harder to avoid errors). I would certainly not recommend it for something that is coped with so easily in conventional ways.

EDIT

Was bored so knocked this up. This is more to show you how hideous it is to return a serialised array rather than a serious piece of code to use. It would be a nightmare to maintain and probably very slow to execute, and I would be surprised if there are not cases where this would fail to provide a valid serialised array. Note that you would need to set the max group concat length to something silly before using this (ie, something like *SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;* or even sillier).

```
SELECT CONCAT('a:', COALESCE(COUNT(sub2.name), 0), ':{', GROUP_CONCAT(user_posts SEPARATOR ''), '}')
FROM
(
    SELECT  users.name,
            CONCAT('s:', LENGTH(users.name), ':"', users.name, '";a:', COALESCE(COUNT(sub1.user_id), 0), ':{', COALESCE(GROUP_CONCAT(all_fields ORDER BY counter SEPARATOR ''), ''), '}') AS user_posts
    FROM users
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
        SELECT user_id, 
                @cnt:=if(@prev_id != user_id, 0, @cnt + 1) AS counter,
                CONCAT('i:', @cnt, ';s:',LENGTH(post),':"', post, '";') AS all_fields,
                @prev_id := user_id
        FROM posts
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT @cnt:=0, @prev_id:=0) sub99
    ) sub1
    ON sub1.user_id = users.id
    GROUP BY users.name
) sub2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT users.id,users.name, posts.post FROM users LEFT JOIN posts ON user.id posts.user_id");
$responce=array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
$responce[$row['id']]['name']=$row['name'];
$responce[$row['id']]['posts'][]=$row['name'];
}
foreach($responce as $array){
$data[]=$array;
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this gives you idea to do what you want. Just polish it up and you will be good. I did that once with a project i was working on

```
$usersPostsArray = array(); // Multi dimensional array to store the users and their posts
$usersQuery = "select distinct name from users";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$usersQuery);
//First loop through the users
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $postsQuery = "select * from posts where user_id = $row[id]"; // Select based on the user
    $postresult = mysqli_query($mysqli,$postsQuery);
    //Then loop through the posts based on the user
    while ($postrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($postresult)){
        array_push($usersPostsArray, $row['name'], $postrow['post']); 
    }

}

// Manipulate your array to get what you want
```

Comment: sorry but nested loop is almost never the solution